# probability : socks and inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: probability

I don't understand how I can use the inclusion-exclusion principle in this type of question :

A guy has 3 pairs of socks, he mix them, and pick randomly 3 pairs of socks. 
- What is the probability that the 3 initial pairs are reconstituted ? 
- What is the probability that no initial pair is reconstituted ?

I used conditional probability to obtain that the first event has probability 1/15, and the second 2/3, but I would like to use the inclusion-exclusion principle somehow.

Edit : second has probability 8/15 as mentionned in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try. We have Red, Blue, Green socks. Six socks in total, we name them: 
$$R,r,G,g,B,b$$
Let's first try a direct enumeration approach, which we can afford since the numbers are small.
I define the sample space $\Omega$ to be the space of all unordered groupings of unordered pairs $((\cdot,\cdot),(\cdot,\cdot),(\cdot,\cdot))$.
Here we have all the elements in this set:

1. **Rr Gg Bb**
2. **Rr** GB gb
3. **Rr** Gb Bg
4. RG rg **Bb**
5. Rg Gr **Bb**
6. RB **Gg** br
7. Rb **Gg** Br
8. RG gb Br
9. RG gB br
10. Rg Gb Br
11. Rg GB br
12. RB gb rG
13. RB Gb rg
14. Rb gB rG
15. Rb GB rg

We see from direct enumeration that the probability of complete recontruction of pairs is, as you said, 1/15.

Now, one could easily solve the second question as well via direct enumeration, obtaining $P_0=8/15$ (our results differ! How did you obtain 2/3? Could well be that my definition of $\Omega$ doesn't ensure all 15 outcomes are equiprobable...even though , by symmetry, I think they should really be!)

How would we solve for a general case (in which, possibly, the number of elements is too large to allow for direct enumeration)? Well, if we manage to compute *the probability $P_>$ of reconstructing at least one pair* then we can find our desired results as $P_0=1-P_>$. Now the event "reconstructing at least one pair" is the *union* of the events X="reconstructing Rr", Y="reconstructing Gg", Z="reconstructing Bb". Inclusion-exclusion principle tells us that we can find the probability of the union of three events X,Y,Z by the formula:
$$P(X\cup Y\cup Z) = P(X)+ P(Y) + P(Z) - P(X\cap Y) - P(X\cap Z) - P(Y\cap Z) + P(X\cap Y\cap Z)$$ 
Now, $P(X) = P(Y) = P(Z) = 1/5$ since a sock has a 1/5 chance to end up with its partner. Also notice that 
$$P(X\cap Y)=P(X\cap Z)=P(Y\cap Z)=P(X\cap Y\cap Z)= \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{15}$$
(they are all equal because if two pairs are reconstructed, also the third will be!).
We can now apply our formula:
$$P_>= P(X\cup Y\cup Z) = \frac{1}{5}+ \frac{1}{5}+ \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{15} - \frac{1}{15} - \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{15} = \frac{7}{15}$$
so that:
$$P_0 = 1-\frac{7}{15} = \frac{8}{15}$$
Which is our desired solution!

Comment: Don't worry. Your outcomes are definitely equiprobable.

Comment: Thanks ! Everything is clear!

Answer (score 3):

Number the initial pairs and for $i=1,2,3$ and let $E_{i}$ denote the
event that pair $i$ is reconstituted.

Then to be found are the probabilities of $E_{1}\cap E_{2}\cap E_{3}$
and $E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}$.

For the first just like you I do not see a way of using PIE that makes things more easy and would go for:

$$P\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\cap E_{3}\right)=P\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)=P\left(E_{2}\mid E_{1}\right)P\left(E_{1}\right)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{5}=\frac{1}{15}$$

PIE combined with symmetry is useful though for the second part:

$$P\left(E_{1}^{\complement}\cap E_{2}^{\complement}\cap E_{3}^{\complement}\right)=$$$$1-P\left(E_{1}\cup E_{2}\cup E_{3}\right)=1-3P\left(E_{1}\right)+3P\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\right)-P\left(E_{1}\cap E_{2}\cap E_{3}\right)=$$$$1-3\cdot\frac{1}{5}+3\cdot\frac{1}{15}-\frac{1}{15}=\frac{8}{15}$$

You found $\frac23$, so check yourself (and me of course) on mistakes.

Comment: Yes, I could find the mistake in my calculation. Thanks !

Comment: You are very welcome.